# After swap rows form doesnt send data, javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a problem, I coded  table with some rows, and after that I need to swap some rows after click:

```
function move_up(x) {

    var cur = x.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cur_upd = cur.previousSibling.previousSibling;

    var temp = cur.innerHTML;
    cur.innerHTML = cur_upd.innerHTML;
    cur_upd.innerHTML = temp;
}               

function move_down(x) {

    var cur = x.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cur_upd = cur.nextSibling.nextSibling;

    var temp = cur.innerHTML;
    cur.innerHTML = cur_upd.innerHTML;
    cur_upd.innerHTML = temp ;

}
```

I have table with rows like this:

```
<tr>
  <TD >
    Typ projektu 1
  </TD>
  <TD  align="center">
     <input type="text" class="order_num" name="x_order_num_PROJECT_TYPE" value="1">
     <input type="checkbox" name="x_PROJECT_TYPE_on" checked>
  </TD>
  <td>
    <a href="#" onclick="move_up(this)">Hore</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="move_down(this)">Dole</a>
  </td>
  <TD align="LEFT">
    <select class="selectbox" name="x_PROJECT_TYPE" style="width: 250px">
      <OPTION VALUE="-1" SELECTED>Všetky</option>
      <OPTION VALUE="1" SELECTED>Fixed price</option>
      <OPTION VALUE="2">Time and materials</option>
    </select>
  </TD>
  <TD>&#x25B2; 
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="x_sort" VALUE="PROJECT_TYPE;asc">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="x_sort" VALUE="PROJECT_TYPE;desc">
     &#x25BC;
  </TD>
</TR>
```

After I click on href 'Hore' or 'Dole' it look good, but problem is, that after swap column when I call form submit, it submit all imputs from all rows except swapped rows. Input from that rows is not submitted. What can be problem?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net that shows the issue?

Comment: there is problem, that all of application is coded in PL/SQL, and it is business app. Problem is that when I push submit button, form send all of imputs as parameters, except of swapped rows, values of this input is like ignored or I dont know what ....

Comment: Any for action? Any onsubmit event handler? any errors in console?

Comment: no errors, form submit correctly, there is exactly 131 inputs in this form and when I push submit without swap rows it submit all of inputs, but when I swap it submit only 124 inputs, and in working with submitted inputs I get null values of swapped rows

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `innerHTML` to move the elements, just move the DOM elements themselves.

```
function move_up(x) {
    var cur = x.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cur_upd = cur.previousSibling.previousSibling;
    var parent = cur.parentNode;
    parent.insertBefore(cur, cur_upd);
}               

function move_down(x) {
    var cur = x.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cur_upd = cur.nextSibling.nextSibling;
    var parent = cur.parentNode;
    parent.insertBefore(cur_upd, cur);    
}
```

If there are any event listeners bound to elements, or the application has variables referencing them, converting them back and forth to HTML will lose that.

Comment: Why do you call `previousSibling` twice? That makes it move up 2 rows, not just one.

Comment: when I use previousSibling only once, it return such text, when I use it twice, it return previous row. Visualy it works great, but in submit there is problem

Comment: Loop over node type 3s `Object.prototype.pSib = function(){
while(this.previousSibling.nodeType == 3){
var node = this.previousSibling;
}
return node;
}`

Comment: @mplungjan Would there be any other types of nodes in a table structure?

Comment: All whitespace in non-ie browsers are textnodes

Comment: in @Barmar solution when i use move_up, then cur_upd is not working and when i use move_down that cur inputs are not submitted